# Flask / WTForms / Jinja2 - preserve form data from HTML url call

Tags: jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am trying to preserve the information from a login form made in Flask when a resend verification button is pressed in HTML. The issue is that button redirects the page without preserving the login information already typed.

As such, is there a way to save / repopulate a form in in Jinja2 / HTML?
Apologies if this is badly phrased, I am very new to web development.

Here is the associated code -
auth.py (within function signup()):

```
 if request.method == 'GET':
    verificationCode = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
    print("Generating: {}".format(verificationCode))
    ret = oled.postPopup(popupRequest(priority=0, time=30, title="Signup Code", message=verificationCode))
    if "Error" in ret:
        flash("Error: Please try again later")
```

signup.html:

```
<span style="float:right;">
     <a href="{{ url_for('auth_bp.signup') }}">Resend Verification</a>
</span>
```

My attempts so far have consisted of saving the information via SessionStorage and repopulating when the form is called again, and calling a new version of the verificationCode function within the Jinja2 HTML (currently working on this).

Thank you, H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: instead of creating a dict or storing the individual elements on the page I decided to call the Python function directly from within the HTML file. In the corresponding app.py (where the render template is defined), [according to the Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/templating/), the resendVerification function (posted above) needs to be declared in a wrapper, like so:

```
@main_bp.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def resendVerification():
        // function code
        pass
return dict(resendVerification=resendVerification)
```

And called within the {% block content %} using:

```
{{ resendVerification() }}
```